# controlling servo via serial in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to control my servos using Arduino serial. what happening is after giving the position value in the terminal the servo successfully turns to the value but after that my code takes up Zero without any input and the servo turns zero. my servo is not holding its position. I am not able to understand why it is taking up zero every time after I entered a value, please help.

**check out my code.**

```
#include<Servo.h>
Servo myServo;
int pos;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myServo.attach(9);
  myServo.write(0);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("enter position: ");    
  while (Serial.available()==0){}          
  pos = Serial.parseInt(); 
  if(pos>=0&&pos<=180){
     myServo.write(pos);
     Serial.print("Turned to ");                   
     Serial.println(pos);
     Serial.flush();               
     }
     else Serial.println("invalid position");
  }
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the code in your question rather than providing a screenshot of it, so that I copy-paste the code into my IDE and dubug issues.

Comment: Anyway, I took my time and wrote down the code from your image. But remember that providing code as an image violates StackOverflow's rule for posting a question. You should only post an image when you cannot explain something without images.

Comment: That isn't code.  That is a picture of some code.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason why you are facing this problem:**

There is no mistake you have made. The `parseInt()` function returns `0` itself when a non-digit character is read. You might think that you are only entering integers, then where will a non-digit come from? But every input in the serial monitor has a "carriage return" or a "linefeed" at the end. That is why the `parseInt()` returns 0.

**What is the solution?**

I will give you two solutions to the problem. Each of them works.

**Solution 1:** Use an alternative of `parseInt()`, such as `Serial.readString().toInt()`. Here is the code for that:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myServo;
int pos;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myServo.attach(9);
  myServo.write(0);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println("Enter position: ");
  while(Serial.available() == 0){};
  pos = Serial.readString().toInt();
  if (pos >= 0 && pos <= 180){
    myServo.write(pos);
    Serial.print("Turned to: ");
    Serial.println(pos);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Invalid postition!");
  }
}
```

**Solution 2:** Set the serial monitor settings to "No line ending." It can be found at the bottom of the serial monitor. Like this:

[image]

Glad to help you out!